# Code converting from 2.4 to 2.7

Tags: python, panda3d

I have something from 2.4 and i'd like to convert it for 2.7 but the problem is, i crash everytime at this string:

```
MovieCasts = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable]:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is there a counterpart to

```
tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable]:
```

for 2.7?

Here is the part of the code itself:

```
MovieCasts = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable]):
AvatarType()(range(6)))
```

Comment: You are missing a `)`, and expressions don't end in `:`.

Comment: Possibly meant `tuple(outmost_iterable)`

Answer (score 3):

1)The bracket `(` does not close at the end.

```
MovieCasts = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable]:
                  ^                                                       ^
```

2) Variables should not contain hyphens (`outmost-iterable`).

3) No operation is done while iterating through the for loop.

```
for x in [outmost-iterable]
```

should be something like

```
x for x in [outmost-iterable]
```

4) Not sure if you really want to use `[ ]`. Doing so you're iterating through only one element.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [x for x in [a]] # b = [[1,2,3]]
c = [x for x in a]   # c = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: It will give you error `>>> MovieCasts = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    MovieCasts = tuple(lambda [outmost-iterable]: for x in [outmost-iterable])
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

You have to close tuple `(`. Please correct the text.

You can achieve convert data to tuple as.

```
MovieCasts = tuple(lambda outmost_iterable: x for x in range(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tup(a): return tuple(i for i in a)
```

or

```
def tup(a): return tuple(a)
print tup(range(10))
#output (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

for your code

```
tuple([outmost-iterable])
```

i think there is no need of using lambda

Comment: thanks gnibbler :) every time forget the basic thing